# URL com duas taxonomias

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou com o seguinte problema..
Tenho duas taxonomias diferentes os "**category**" padrões que são por ex: cultura, esporte, política.
E uma taxonomia customizada que é "**cat_especiais**" que tem por ex.. "infografias,perfil,grande reportagem..", e tenho um arquivo taxonomy-cat_especiais.php que acessa os posts que tem marcado alguma dessas categorias de especiais.. Até aí nenhum problema.

Agora a pergunta: Se eu quiser acessar os posts que tem tanto algum "category" quanto um "cat_especiais" marcados existe algum arquivo que dê suporte ao loop padrão do Wordpress? Falo, sem necessidade de eu criar um page com uma query passando argumentos. 
Fazendo apenas o

```
if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe algo para arquivo misto com duas taxonomias diferentes como você quer e de forma nativa no WordPress.
Se você quer algo assim precisa ser customizado, criando um arquivo usando [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).